# Is there a procedure to "TAG" an OWL class?

Tags: owl

I have an ontology with a set of OWL declarations like this:

```
Declaration(Class(<http://www.myontology.org/#TAG1-person>))
Declaration(Class(<http://www.myontology.org/#TAG2-animal>))
Declaration(Class(<http://www.myontology.org/#TAG1-child>))
Declaration(Class(<http://www.myontology.org/#TAG2-insect>))
```

In this way I'm *decorating* the ontology with these TAGs placed as part of the OWL Class name.
I need this because I want to filter specific OWL classes having that TAG.

Actually it works fine in my program, but I'm asking this question to understand if there is a better way to do this, since if I want to check if an OWL Class has a specific TAG, I have no other choice to iterate all of them and check if it contains the TAG. This means string comparison and computationally speaking it's heavy.

So, is OWL equipped with native data structures to do the same?

Comment: labels (via `rdfs:label`) or any other kind of annotation property. Encoding such information inside the URI is worst practice

Comment: Annotations or punning: https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-owl2-syntax-20121211/#Metamodeling

Comment: Thanks. I'm using OWLAPI in Java. Do I have to use annotation? Because I can't find a function related to an OWL class called like "label".

Comment: Yes,  labels are annotations.